# OpenCV - Loop an image as Webcam Input

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I began using OpenCV(Python) a while ago and everything went great until now. My Webcam broke and now I cant use it to test my code. Is there a way to fake the input with a simple image? It's not perfect but should be fine for simple things until the new webcam arrives.

Let's assume I have something like this:

```js
windowWidth = 640
windowHeight = 840
brightness = 100

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3,windowWidth)
cap.set(4,windowHeight)
cap.set(10,brightness)



while (cap.isOpened()):
    success, img = cap.read()
    if success== True:
        img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
        cv2.imshow("output", img)
        if cv2.waitKey(1)& 0xFF ==ord("q"):
            break
```

This should work fine but now with the broken camera I would like to be able to "fake" the input with an image but still be able to test it just like I would using a webcam.

Something along the lines of `cap = cv2.imread(testImg.PNG)` which obviously does not work. I am looking for something along the lines of maybe looping the image into the webcam input to create some sort of working setup since a video is nothing more than a lot of frames in series playing.

Any suggestions are appreciated :)

Comment: Why is this tagged C++ and JavaScript? Are you using those languages?

Comment: You could use [pyfakewebcam](https://github.com/jremmons/pyfakewebcam) ?

Comment: I found that too but it's apparently only compatible with Linux, I am using Win10

Comment: Apparently you can emulate a camera with [splitcamera](https://splitcamera.com/), that should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VideoCapture` is a class to interface with video streams, and a single image is returned via call to its `read()` method. When you call `cap = cv2.imread()`, you are replacing the newly created `VideoCapture` instance with `np.ndarray` instance which is returned by `cv2.imread`.
I believe that replacing

`success, img = cap.read()`

with

`img = cv2.imread(testImg.PNG)`

would solve your problem.

Comment: That did the trick, i just had to adjust `if success== True:` to always be true so i just made it `if True== True:` for a quick and dirty solution. Thanks m8